# LUIS get all intents list with all the labeled utterance inside

Tags: c#, azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am building LUIS application. And currently I want to get all the intent list including all the labeled utterance for each intent. I look into the Microsoft cognitive service API list. I only found this API:

```
"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}/intents?skip=0&take=100"
```

that API can only get all the intents available in my system. How can I get all the labeled utterance for each intent?

Comment: I don't suppose the [Review Labeled Examples](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a) call is what you need, is it?

Comment: nope. it doesnt give me the labeled utterance,

Comment: there is no api available currently....I have raised similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884634/get-id-of-all-intent-and-utterances-after-import/56962173#56962173

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything you can do in the portal, you can do via APIs. When you are in the portal, keep dev tools open, and watch the REST api to LUIS and the response. The one that comes to mind is exporting your app because the app json definition has the utterances and the entities.