# Get id of all intent and utterances after import

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

So have created two applications on Luis and I wanted to import second application into first application. So I did the following:

1. [Export](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40) second Application
2. [Import](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5892283039e2bb0d9c2805f5) into first application
3. [Train](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c45) first application
4. [Publish](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c3b) first application

Now I want to get id's of trained intent and utterances but I am not able to find any Luis API to do so. Without any id's, I am not to do delete and update intent or utterances programatically.

How can I get complete LUIS application details(intent,entity,utterances) including id's and other metadata after importing from another application?

Answer (score 1):

The LUIS programmatic APIs have two endpoints you can query to get intents and utterances. You can access the LUIS APIs by clicking [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/), locate 'LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0', and follow the link. *I don't want to post the actual link as it's a bit complex and likely to change/break.*

Once on the page, find the API menu on the left. Then:

- Expand 'model' and look for 'Get version intent list', and
- Expand 'example utterances' and look for 'Review labeled examples'

These each, respectively, should provide you with the lists you are looking for. Simply provide the necessary credentials.

Hope of help!

Comment: I am able to get intent id's using 'Get version intent list' but 'Review labeled examples' gives only examples to be reviewed and not the complete list of utterances with id's